# Why aren't global variables inherited dynamically like methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, dynamic, static

I'm writing a subclass Sub in Java which extends Sandwich and testing to see which attributes and behaviors get passed to the child class and why.

If I write it this way:

```
  public class Sub extends Sandwich{

      public Sub(){}

      public String flavor(){
        return "Delicious vinegar";
      }
   }
```

Then in my main I write:

```
Sandwich x = new Sub();
```

x.flavor() will return "Delicious vinegar", unless flavor() is not defined in Sandwich. However, if flavor is an attribute, it uses Sandwich's flavor instead of Sub's.

```
public class Sub extends Sandwich{
  public String taste;
  public Sub(){
    taste = "Delicious vinegar";
  }
```

I did not declare taste as static, yet x.taste will return whatever Sandwich's *taste* variable is (even if using an accessor method) instead of Sub's *taste* (or an error if Sandwich doesn't define *taste*). Does this have to do with the way the constructor is set up? I didn't declare any method or variable static.

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic. Global or otherwise.

Comment: Is there a certain reason for that, or just kind of the way it is?

Comment: you would want to use super() if you want to achieve what you want.